# Jest and React Native: How to mock AccessibilityInfo

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, mocking, jestjs

I'm testing my react native app with Jest and the following line gives me an issue.

```
AccessibilityInfo.announceForAccessibility(errorMessages[0]);
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'announceForAccessibility' of undefined
```

I've tried to mock it using

```
jest.mock('react-native', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-native'),
  AccessibilityInfo: {
    fetch: jest.fn(),
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
    setAccessibilityFocus: jest.fn(),
    announceForAccessibility: jest.fn(),
    removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
  },
}));
```

but that brought a whole lot of other issues.

How could I mock this specific export on the react native package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue when using `AccessibilityInfo.fetch()` to determine if the user is using a screen reader.

One option for named imports is to use the spyOn method.

```
import { AccessibilityInfo } from 'react-native';

jest
  .spyOn(AccessibilityInfo, 'announceForAccessibility')
  .mockImplementation(...);
```